# fprintf() writes data in text format regardless to the mode I use in fopen() to open the file

Tags: c, file-io, integer, binaryfiles, fwrite

Trying to store an int in binary mode using `fprintf()` but no matter which mode I specify in `fopen()` it is writing int value only in text format. On the  other hand when i use `fwrite` in place of `fprintf` it stores the int in binary format. So can we use `fprintf` in binary mode?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("abc.bin", "wb");
    int num = 69;
    fprintf(fp, "%d", num);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Also if we talk about other I/O functions which of them will work perfectly with binary mode? Is there anything officially documented about such behaviors ?

I am working on windows platform under mingw.

Comment: `fprintf` with `%d` is always going to convert an integer to a sequence of characters.  That's the definition of what it does.  If you want to write the data in its raw binary form, use `fwrite`.

Comment: So to actually store the data in raw binary form can we use any other function apart from `fwrite` ?

Comment: `fwrite` is the `stdio` function used to write raw binary data.  Note that the difference between opening a file with `"w"` vs. `"wb"` is fairly minor.  It really only affects how newlines are handled on Windows systems. On Unix systems it doesn't matter.

Comment: oh so that means it is actually the `fwrite` that is responsible for writing raw binary data and not the `wb` mode ? and is it perfectly fine than if i use `fwrite` with `w` mode ? as the data will get stored in binary format again. Am i right ?? If yes than what is the use of binary mode. Why windows has made such a concept in first place ?

Comment: Using `"wb"` for binary data is safer.  It guarantees your data won't be altered.  The risk with using `"w"` on a Windows system is that it if you write a byte that looks like a newline, there's a risk that it will insert a carriage return character in front of it.  It's unfortunate that Windows made the wrong choice very early on about how to handle end-of-line, but that's the way it is now.

Comment: To be fair, Windows didn't invent the cr/lf end-of-line sequence.  It was used by most of the DEC operating systems, while Unix used a single linefeed character.  So Windows did what DEC did, before Unix became as popular as it is today.  Just use `"wb"` for files that contain binary data and `"w"` for text files and you won't have any problems.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf()` is meant to convert `int` arguments to human readable format. To store binary data to your file, you must indeed open it in binary mode with `"wb"` or `"ab"` and you can use `fwrite` or `putc`:

```
int n = 1234;
if (fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fp) == 1) {
    // n was successfully written to fp
}
```

`fwrite` stores the `int` value using the representation and byte order in use in the running system. If the file can be transferred to a different system to be read there, you must specify the byte order and representation used in the file and implement the read and write functions in a portable manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int write_int32_le(int n, FILE *fp) {
    /* write the int as a 4 byte little endian two's complement representation */
    uint32_t u32 = n;
    int res = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (putc(u32 & 255, fp) == EOF)
            res = EOF;
        u32 >>= 8;
    }
    return res;
}

int read_int32_le(FILE *fp) {
    /* write the int as a 4 byte little endian two's complement representation */
    uint32_t u32 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int c = getc(fp);
        if (c == EOF)
            return EOF;
        u32 |= (uint32_t)c << (i << 3);
    }
    return (int)u32;
}
```

Other representations could be used in your binary file, such as big-endian or [LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128)